# WPF application which embed winform controls and winform usercontrols

Tags: c#

This question might be a little vague but I've created a WPF application and I was wondering if I can embed winform controls and winform user controls.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx).

Comment: So I have a software developed in WinForm but I want to change it to WPF. So using WindowsFormsHost, what's the easiest way for me to change the entire project to WPF.

Comment: There is no easy way to change your entire project to WPF. You can host individual controls and components inside WindowsFormsHosts, but all this will do is embed the WinForms inside WPF. It will not automagically make your application WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  There is a "WindowsFormHost" control for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A vague question gets a vague answer: Yes, it's pretty straightforward. Look at the System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost control.